# Who is the Killer from the following suspect in this image?

Tags: visual, lateral-thinking, story

[image]

I did a lot of image search on google and found out the original source of the image is  http://www.ghadahaleidi.com/

because there is a lot of debate I posted the answer myself and here are the different sources of the answer. These article with answers have an oldest posted date, the articles with answer deep suggests are part of brain puzzle category and someone did it just for a prank (the article of gpuzzle do not have a post date) they are hiding the post date of article 
**Answer spoiler alert ( don't look)**

> [ladiespassiton.com](https://ladiespassiton.com/2017/09/27/who-is-the-killer/#comments) 
>  [truthinsideofyou.org](https://www.truthinsideofyou.org/who-is-the-killer/) 
>  *The answer is 4 because of the scratch on his neck, the knife is missing and torn piece of his shirt is near the victim.* You are assuming the red thing near the women is blood but it is not blood but the torn piece of the killer shirt which is also missing from the killer end if you see carefully.

As you can see in the image there is a woman on the left who got killed by one of the following suspect tags by number 1,2,3,4 you can see them on the right side of the image. justify your answer with proper statement will be accepted.

> Hint 1: a waiter is bringing a glass of water but 3 & 4 is already having
>  one.
>  
>  Hint 2: Everyone is having at least 2 chairs with the table but only
>  suspect 4 is having 1 chair?
>  
>  Hint 4: 3 & 4 can be watched easily by 2 and nobody is watching 1 & 2.
>  
>  Hint 5: the chair behind 2 seems like someone recently moved from
>  there.
>  
>  Hint 6: suspect 4 is not having a knife with him and his shirt tucked
>  out but there is more. 
>  Hint7: why there is no purse with the women who died? 
>  Hint8: There is no table with extra food that means the women just came in and went to the washroom to wash her hands. 
>  Hint9: Suspect 2 is having the best view he can watch everyone from that point. the chair behind him seems misplaced. 
>  Hint10: it seems like there is a scratch on the neck of suspect 4 
>  Hint11: we don't know anything about suspect 1 he is sitting idle not ordered any food yet. we can't see his table also nobody is watching on him. 
>  Hint12: apart from suspects waiter can move freely from one place to another he can get a knife from any table easily. He can also access ladies washroom quietly we don't know where the door is for washroom

Comment: I'm not sure why people are voting to close this as off-topic. @Stiv It's fine to use puzzles from elsewhere, with appropriate attribution - a significant proportion, and probably a majority in some tags/genres, of our questions are such.

Comment: @RandalThor Guess I just felt that since the question entirely replicates a puzzle from elsewhere without adding any additional info, discussion or a new angle there doesn't really seem a lot of point putting it up on PSE too. It's already on the web - why add it again? It just felt to me like an attempt to gain some easy rep without going to the effort of making a new puzzle. By all means link to other puzzles for help, clarification, education or putting a twist on it, but surely we don't just want PSE to become a repository for any old puzzle already on the internet?

Comment: This was put on hold because it's clearly taken from elsewhere and not properly attributed. I see there are some reopen votes, so let me clarify: a link to the front page of what looks like a giant clickbait site, which may or may not have a copy of this puzzle somewhere on it, does not count as proper attribution. (The link in DEEM's answer would count as proper attribution, if Gpuzzles is where this originally comes from, which I think it is.)

Comment: Though if reopened it might well get closed again as "too broad"; I agree with all the other people who've said that the puzzle doesn't in fact have enough information in it to make there be a single correct answer. (The Gpuzzles answer is surely the creator's intended one, but it's a _terrible_ answer.) Fundamentally, I'm afraid this is just a bad puzzle.

Comment: A large number of comments were [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/99084/discussion-on-question-by-sayed-mohd-ali-who-is-the-killer-from-the-following-su). Please be reminded that *comments are not for extended discussion or debate* — they are intended to help improve a post, not to debate the validity of a question or the merits of an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think it's probably

> Suspect 4

For a few reasons

> 1. He seems to be missing his knife (the murder weapon)
>  2. He's wearing a red shirt (which would cover any suspicious blood spatter).
>  3. His appearance is dishevelled (shirt untucked in several places) indicating that he may recently have been involved in a struggle.
>  4. In cases of homicide, the perpetrator is male 96% of the time.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately this is an old puzzle from Gpuzzles

https://www.gpuzzles.com/brain-questions/mystery-puzzles-and-riddles/latest/2

> The answer given there is Number 3 because only ladies can go in the
>  ladies WC

Comment: Ah okay, didn't see this. Not a convincing reason I think, someone who has the capacity to kill another person probably wouldn't be dissuaded from walking into the opposite sex bathroom.

Comment: @DEEM can you justify your answer? why would she will be the only women sitting there, rest of all are men. she knows that she will become the 1st suspect of the murder according to your theory ? why she didn't left?

Comment: Process of elimination. If Men had gone in the women WC somebody would have noticed

Answer (score -3):

@hexomino already answered the question but I will explain to you what happened... it is riddle of picture, visual riddle so you need to use visual clues and IQ to solve it and not stories. whatever I am mentioning is based on visual clues in the picture.

our prime suspect is 1, 2, 3 and 4... 
Suspect 3:

> **Suspect 3 seems clear:**  obviously first doubt will go on the lady she is the only lady in the restaurant and it is easier to think by
>  every one that she is the murderer. 
>  
>   1. if she has done the murder why she is still sitting there? she got the scarf she should try to leave while covering her face. if she
>  covers her whole face nobody will doubt her because she is a Muslim
>  woman.
>   2. it is difficult for women to stab another woman from the front even in the washroom without any noise. she needs to keep cover her
>  mouth with one hand whole time until she dies. this cannot be done by
>  women...
>   3. The girl hasn't ordered yet because she is waiting for her friend.  As you can see everyone is having food on their table but the waiter
>  is busy in serving suspect 3, the waiter is bringing a glass of water
>  for the women (suspect 3) because of she just came-in to have food
>  along with the women who died. the stuff on the table of suspect 3 is
>  of women who died, she left her purse, the empty glass of water on the
>  table and went to the washroom to wash her hands. that means they both
>  are friends.

**Suspect 1**

> **Seems to be clear:** suspect 1 seems to be the most suspicious person, we can't see anything on his table. but what makes him clear
>  is his sitting position. if he wants to go inside women washroom and
>  kill the women then he needs the best seat to keep an eye on the
>  others to easily move in and move out from women washroom. And it
>  seems to be like the women is along with suspect 3 that is the
>  long-distance to keep an eye like that.

**Suspect 4:** 
The fourth person i.e. the man in a redshirt.

> 1. He is sitting near the toilet so its easier for him to murder and then quickly come back to his seat. 
>  
>   2. His red shirt is also a good cover for any blood spill that may
>      occur due to murder.
>   3. His shirt is also tucked out which shows he was in a hurry. 
>  
>   4. it seems like a torn piece of his shirt is under the victim 
>  
>   5. He is pretending to use a knife... most activities with a knife require both hands except the murder. 
>  
>   6. Mostly women washroom and men washroom are next to each other because they both need water supply and flushing system. so with small
>  chance by keeping eyes #2 and waiter he can easily go in and come out.
>  
>   7. he is having a scratch on his neck...

**Suspect 2:**

> **seems to be clear** 
>  1) he is having a knife, busy in eating. there is nothing suspicious about him.

Comment: The reasoning for suspect 3 makes no sense. Point #1 would make them *more* suspicious. Point #2 doesn't do anything to differentiate between men and women. Point #3 is ambiguous.

Comment: @Adam for a women to kill another women with knife in washroom without any noise and struggle? is it even possible?

Comment: This is an issue of strength, it has nothing to do with your sex. I don't know how you can determine someones strength based off of an image. Even then the motion required to pull off such a stunt would be challenging for a strong person. Although this whole issue can be avoided if you consider that it is possible the victim was in a weakened state

Comment: @Adam it is mentioned in the image that the victim is in weakened state? as you can see in the image both women are of normal size, yes you can determine the strength by looking at their body. go with the clues in the image don't make your own assumption, in the case women was not killed she did suicide she was stressed out .... are your happy now? I mentioned the clues in the image... the man in red shirt gave the most of the clues...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/98528/discussion-between-adam-and-sayed-mohd-ali).